# Whitespace between PHP start tag and namespace

Tags: php, coding-style

Should there be a space between `<?php` and `namespace` inside a php class file?

I am looking for this information in PSR guidelines. There are indication about a space after. But before?

[PSR-2-coding-style-guid](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PSR-2 Its purpose is to have a single style guide for PHP code that results in uniformly formatted shared code.

- Code MUST use 4 spaces for indenting, not tabs.
- There MUST NOT be a hard limit on line length; the soft limit MUST be 120 characters; lines SHOULD be 80 characters or less.
- There MUST be one blank line after the namespace declaration, and there MUST be one blank line after the block of usedeclarations
- Opening braces for classes MUST go on the next line, and closing braces MUST go on the next line after the body.
- Opening braces for methods MUST go on the next line, and closing braces MUST go on the next line after the body.
- Visibility MUST be declared on all properties and methods; abstract and final MUST be declared before the visibility; static MUST be
  declared after the visibility
- Control structure keywords MUST have one space after them; method and function calls MUST NOT.
- Opening braces for control structures MUST go on the same line, and closing braces MUST go on the next line after the body.
- Opening parentheses for control structures MUST NOT have a space after them, and closing parentheses for control structures MUST NOT
  have a space before.

## Basic Coding Standard [PSR-2]

*Files

- All PHP files MUST use the Unix LF (linefeed) line ending.
- All PHP files MUST end with a single blank line.
- The closing ?> tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.

Lines

- There MUST NOT be a hard limit on line length.
- The soft limit on line length MUST be 120 characters; automated style checkers MUST warn but MUST NOT error at the soft limit.
- Lines SHOULD NOT be longer than 80 characters; lines longer than that SHOULD be split into multiple subsequent lines of no more than
  80 characters each.
- There MUST NOT be trailing whitespace at the end of non-blank lines.
- Blank lines MAY be added to improve readability and to indicate related blocks of code.
- There MUST NOT be more than one statement per line.

Indenting

- Code MUST use an indent of 4 spaces, and MUST NOT use tabs for indenting.

Keywords and True/False/Null

- PHP keywords MUST be in lower case. ( e.g. echo , die, for, throw, catch )
- The PHP constants true, false, and null MUST be in lower case

NameSpace and Use Declaration

- When present, there MUST be one blank line after the namespace declaration.
- When present, all use declarations MUST go after the namespace declaration.
- There MUST be one use keyword per declaration.
- There MUST be one blank line after the use block.

Comment: no mentions about what should be happens before namespace =)

Comment: there should not be space before namespace

Comment: What? This is just a copy and paste of some of PSR. It doesn't directly answer the question at all.